# A problem with DrawRoundRect size

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, mobile, drawing

I'm trying to create a custom button with ActionScript 3.0. I'm suing a round rect as background, but I have a problem with it size.

This is my custom button class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class customButton extends Sprite
    {
        private var background:Shape;
        public var bgColor:uint;
        public var borderColor:uint;
        public var borderSize:uint;
        public var cornerRadius:uint;
        private var label:TextField;

        public function customButton(text:String)
        {
            super();

            this.opaqueBackground = 0xFF0000;

            background = new Shape();
            borderSize = 1;
            borderColor = 0x666666;
            bgColor = 0xFFCC00;
            cornerRadius = 9;

            label = new TextField();
            label.text = text;

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Verdana";
            format.color = 0;
            format.size = 38;
            format.underline = true;

            label.defaultTextFormat = format;

            addChild(background);
            addChild(label);

            buttonMode = true;
            mouseChildren = false;
        }

        public function draw():void
        {
            background.graphics.lineStyle(borderSize, borderColor);
            background.graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
            background.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height cornerRadius);
            background.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code used to show the button:

```
    public function Test01()
    {
        super();

        // support autoOrients
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        button = new customButton("Button");
        button.x = 200;
        button.y = 300;
        button.width = 200;
        button.height = 100;
        button.draw();

        addChild(button);
    }
```

If I set this size to the button:

```
button.width = 200;
button.height = 100;
```

I get the following:

[image]

But I set it to button size:

button.width = 40;
button.height = 20;

(This size is the same used in customButton class). I get:

[image]

I don't know why when I use a size of (40, 20) I get a smaller rectangle than that size.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is happening because you are setting the width directly to the `Sprite`, it changes the size of the sprite no the size of the background you are drawing.

in your customButton class add some code:

```
private var _width:Number = 10;
private var _height:Number = 10;

override public function get width():Number { return _width; }      
override public function set width(value:Number):void 
{
    _width = value;
    draw ();
}

override public function get height():Number { return _height; }        
override public function set height(value:Number):void 
{
    _height = value;
    draw ();
}

private function draw():void
{
    background.graphics.clear ()
    background.graphics.lineStyle(borderSize, borderColor);
    background.graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
    background.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, _width, _height, cornerRadius);
    background.graphics.endFill();
}
```

with this code you will be able to chnage the background size everytime, and you will not be affecting the other components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use it, setting size to (40, 20), I get this: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/9576/errorbutton.png

Comment: This is correct you getting. Bhe button background is 40x20 px. But you are using `opaqueBackground=0xFF0000` property so it means all your background of the displayObject in this case customButton will be filled with red background. The big red area you having is the TextField influence, beacause by default TF size is 100x100. to prevent this you should use: `label.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;`

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class customButton extends Sprite
    {
        private var background:Shape;
        public var bgColor:uint;
        public var borderColor:uint;
        public var borderSize:uint;
        public var cornerRadius:uint;
        public var bWidth:Number;
        public var bHeight:Number;
        private var label:TextField;

        public function customButton(text:String, bW:Number, bH:Number)
        {
            super();
            this.bWidth = bW;
            this.bHeight = bH;

            background = new Shape();
            borderSize = 1;
            borderColor = 0x666666;
            bgColor = 0xFFCC00;
            cornerRadius = 9;

            label = new TextField();
            label.text = text;

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Verdana";
            format.color = 0;
            format.size = 38;
            format.underline = true;

            label.defaultTextFormat = format;

            addChild(background);
            addChild(label);

            buttonMode = true;
            mouseChildren = false;
            background.graphics.lineStyle(borderSize, borderColor);
            background.graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
            background.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, bWidth, bHeight, cornerRadius);
            background.graphics.endFill();
        }

    }
}
```

TRy this

Answer (score 0):

Your roundRect class size has been fixed, so that it was making no changes when u r increasing the width.

Make two public parameters for both width(Bwidth) and height(Bheight) and access it.

like

```
button.Bwidth = 100;
```